Power Automate - Getting Values from a Sharepoint Item Dropdown List
I have two Sharepoint lists. I have a flow that does the following:
When a new item is created in List A, create a new item in List B; fill some of the fields in the new List B item with the values of some of the fields in the existing List A item.
This is easy and works fine for text fields; in the flow, I just set the value for the text fields in the List B item to be the values of the corresponding text fields in the List A item.
But I cannot figure out dropdowns. List B has a dropdown field; in the new List B item, I want that field to be populated by the value of a field in List A which is also a dropdown.
In the flow, I set the value of the dropdown field in the new List B item to "(dropdown field from List A)/Value"
I expected this to populate the dropdown field in the new List B item with the value from the dropdown field in List A.
Instead, I got an "Input parameter 'item/PROD_AP_INSPECTOR/Id' is required to be of type 'Integer/int64'" error when running the flow.
Can anyone help with this? Thank you!
